# Convert.ToDouble , Convert.ToInt32

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

Im having a trouble to convert the function from asp.net to jquery

```
Convert.ToDouble
Convert.ToInt32
```

please look at my code and tell me how to convert it right

thanks

```
 function paint(orders) {
             var table = $('#progressgrid')
                        '<div style="border: 1px; width: 600px; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;">';
             $.each(orders, function () {
                 table +=    
                   '<div style="float: left;">' + this.PdriverName + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + '</div>' +
                    '<div style="border: 3px solid black; float: left; width: <%# Convert.ToInt32(this.OrderCount) * 50 %>px">' +
                     '<div style="border: 0px; float: left; width: <%# ((Convert.ToDouble(this.OrderCount) - Convert.ToDouble(this.OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull)) / Convert.ToDouble(this.OrderCount)) * 100 %>%;">' + this.OrderCount + '</div>' +
                      '<div style="border: 0px; float: right; width: <%# (Convert.ToDouble(this.OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull) / Convert.ToDouble(this.OrderCount)) * 100 %>%; background-color: red;">' + this.OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull + '</div>'
```

Comment: there are `parseInt` and `parseFloat`

Comment: I don't get it, you are just displaying values. Why does it matter if they are ints, floats or just plain strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
parseInt(str);
parseFloat(str);
```

Comment: can you please show me how to use it in '<div style="border: 0px; float: left; width: <%# ((Convert.ToDouble(this.OrderCount) - Convert.ToDouble(this.OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull)) / Convert.ToDouble(this.OrderCount)) * 100 %>%;">' + this.OrderCount + '</div>' +

Answer (score 1):

you've a double % sign in your code, you meant multiplied by 100% but the parser took it as an end statement. double check that.

```
parseInt(<%# this.OrderCount * 50 %>)
```